# Expressing quadratic form using coordinates in new orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e=[e_1,e_2,e_3]$ be orthogonal basis in euclidean vector space $V$ and let $\phi(v) = 3x^2 + 6y^2 +3z^2 -4xy +2xz -4yz$ and $v=xe_1 + ye_2 + ze_3$. Express $\phi$ using coordinates $x', y',z'$ in new orthogonal basis $f$.

I have already computed orthogonal basis $f$ and found coordinate transformations which are:

$x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x' + \frac{1}{\sqrt3}y' + \frac{1}{\sqrt6}z'$

$y= \frac{1}{\sqrt3}y' + \frac{2}{\sqrt6}z'$

$z=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x' + \frac{1}{\sqrt3}y' + \frac{1}{\sqrt6}z'$

So should i just plug in eqations above in quadratic form and that's it or i need to do something else.

On top of that the canonical form of this quadratic form is $\phi(v) = 8(x')^2 + 2(y')^2 + 2(z')^2$ and isn't this already "expressing  $\phi$ using  coordinates $x', y',z'$ ?

Comment: Assuming you are using $x',y',z'$ consistently: yes, you already have the answer.

Comment: I've been checking this over and over again, and to me it doesn't look like your last two basis elements in the second coordinate system are orthogonal. I computed the matrix of the associated bilinear form to be $M=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&-2&1\\ -2&6&-2\\ 1&-2&3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and if the inverse of the transformation you gave is $A$, then $A^TMA$ ought to be diagonal, but it isn't. I could have typoed something, though.

Comment: And what do you mean by "canonical form"? I guess you're working over the real numbers, so unless I'm missing something, you can further scale the second basis until the form becomes $(x')^2+(y')^2+(z')^2$... why are $8$ and $2$ special?